# How to check if a value is literally null

Tags: c++, null, arduinojson

I have an JSON object like this:

```json
{ "foo": null }
```

How do I check if the value of foo is a literal `null`. I found the function [JsonObject::isNull()](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonobject/isnull/) but that apparently is for

> testing whether the JsonObject points to an object or not

That is not what I want my code to check, but I couldn't find a solution to this problem.

Comment: The docs suggest https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonvariant/isnull/

Comment: The documentation does suggest that `JsonVariant::isNull` is checking if the `JsonVariant` itself is a valid pointer into a `JsonDocument`, rather than whether or not the pointed-to JSON value is `null` instead of something else.

Comment: @NathanPierson, There's an example on the page where it returns true for a null value as desired. It seems you still have to do something like `containsKey` manually to differentiate, though.

Comment: Ah, thank you all. The `isNull` in combination with the `containsKey` seems to work. To **serialize** a null value I found that `doc["foo"] = nullptr` works.

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc: https://arduinojson.org/v6/issues/cannot-use-null/

- If c++11 is available (which has `nullptr`), you can check if the json object's value is null or not like so:

```
if (!doc["foo"]) {}
```

or

```
if (doc["foo"] == nullptr) {}
```

- If c++11 is not available, you can use the `isNull()` method:

```
if (doc["foo"].isNull()) {}
```

Comment: Just note that using `doc["foo"].isNull()` does not differentiate between the document not containing a `"foo"` value at all versus having a `"foo"` value that is `null`. If you want to differentiate, use `doc.containsKey("foo")`. This library doesn't really seem to handle `null` very well.  Most JSON libraries I've worked with represent `null` as its own type that can be handled specifically. This library doesn't seem to do that.